# How to create an one dimension array excel funciton with a value X times?

Tags: arrays, excel, function, multidimensional-array

Is this any option or function in the Excel, which one i can create a one dimension array X times with a value?

Here an example, i give for input the value + how many times i want create, and i get this result.

My value:       50
How many?       5

50
50
50
50
50

Answer (score 0):

Does the type it is stored as matter? You can convert back to numeric when emptying the array for example. String at present so can use Rept and Split. You can input numbers or strings to the function.

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim myArr() As String

    myArr = GetArray(5, 50)

    Dim i As Long

    'Example print out of contents
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

        Debug.Print CLng(myArr(i)) 'Example type conversion to Long

    Next i

End Sub

Public Function GetArray(ByVal howMany As Long, ByVal myValue As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Arr() As String

    ReDim Arr(howMany - 1)

    Dim myString As String

    myString = Trim$(Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept(myValue & Chr(32), howMany))

    Arr = Split(myString, Chr(32))

    GetArray = Arr

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub myvalue()
    Dim myval As String
    Dim times As Long
    Dim i As Long
    myval = InputBox("My Value is :")
    times = InputBox("How many times :")
    ReDim array1(times - 1)
    For i = 0 To times - 1
        array1(i) = myval
        Debug.Print "Array " & i & " : is " & myval
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Input:**

My Value is : 50

How many times : 5

**Output**

Array 0 : is 50

Array 1 : is 50

Array 2 : is 50

Array 3 : is 50

Array 4 : is 50

Comment: I insert it to a button. How can i write this output to T1,T2,T3...TX cells?

Comment: And how can be my input is a cell? and not a box?

Comment: remove debug.print line and add this line `Range("T"&Range("T"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1).Value=myval`

Comment: remove line myval = InputBox("My Value is :") and add `myval = Range("S10").Value`